# Searching text/tags from one side of an associative table in MySQL, and returning data from the other

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table structure something like this (this is a massive simplification):

```
Posts
    UID
    Title
    Text ID (linked to Text.UID)

Tags
    UID
    Tag Name
    Tag Description

Tag Associations
    UID
    Post UID (linked to Posts.UID)
    Tag UID (linked to Tags.UID)

Text
    UID
    Text
```

I'd like to know two things:

A) How can I make a query to return all the information from the Posts table (including the text from the Text table), for all "Posts" associated with a specific tag (searched by plaintext), without duplicates, when a single post may contain up to 20 tags?

For example, a tag could be "PHP," and I'd want to return all posts with the "PHP" tag associated with them.

B) Additionally, I'd like to include ALL tag names associated with each post, but I'm not sure if this can be done in one query.

I'm using prepared statements, and displaying multiple, full posts at a time from the search, with all their tags, and would rather not have to run separate queries to return the post and all its tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  Posts.Title AS Title,
  Text.Text AS Text,
  (
    SELECT Tags.*
    FROM Tags
    INNER JOIN TagAssociations ON Tags.UID = TagAssociations.TagUID
    WHERE TagAssociations.PostUID = Posts.UID
 ) AS Tags
FROM Posts
INNER JOIN Text ON Posts.UID = Text.UID
INNER JOIN TagAssociations ON Posts.UID = TagAssociations.PostUID
INNER JOIN Tags ON Tags.UID = TagAssociations.TagUID
WHERE Tags.TagName = 'search'
```

I don't think the subquery is going to work, but you can give it a try.